# My SMTP server can't process the incoming DATA of certain SMTP server

Tags: sockets, email, smtp, readline

We used a SMTP server to receive emails, It works perfectly when I send an email to my server from gmail or hotmail. But I'm having problems with a specific company ( I will name it company x), we can read the sender, the recipient, etc, but when it comes to the DATA, the buffered reader hangs forever reading the line on the socket.

This is what happen when I receive the email from the company x:

1. When I receive a company x's email. they send me the EHLO command
2. my server returns 500 command unrecognised
3. the company x's server send the HELO command
4. my server sends 250 ok  to the company x's server.
5. the copany x's server send me `MAIL From: <sender@email.com>`
6. my server sends 250 ok
7. the company x's server send me `RCPT To:<recipient@email.com>`
8. my server sends 250 ok
9. the company x's server sends DATA
10. my server sends 354 Start mail input; end with `<CRLF>.<CRLF>`

At this moment the server hangs forever reading the incoming data (in the `in.readline()`) and my server throws socket time out exception. (obviously we tried increasing the time out, but it didn't work)

what could be the difference with the company x's SMTP server and the gmail or hotmail server??, what is the problem???

We have the same error with the Java mail server and the james mail server.

The company x, is a bank so they have a high information security level.

here is the code how we send it.

```
private static final String MESSAGE_SEND_DATA = "354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>";
```

and this is the method that write the comand on the outputstream.

```
private void write( String message ) {

        if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) { log.debug( "Writing: " + message ); }
        out.print( message + "\r\n" );
        out.flush();
    }
```

we call write after we receive the data commanx from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it hangs forever awaiting for line terminator symbol. `BufferedReader#readLine` is platform dependent in terms of line terminators, so it's a poor Reader choice for SMTP server implementation. As a matter of fact, I would advice not to use `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter` for socket-originated streams to avoid platform-dependent issues like this one.

All SMTP server implementations in Java I'm aware of (Apache James, SubethaSMTP) use dedicated Reader implementations, focused on CRLF-terminated lines to read lines from a Socket, in full accordance with [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). So my advice would be to try one of these readers (for example [this one](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.subethamail/subethasmtp-smtp/1.0.3/org/subethamail/smtp/server/io/CRLFTerminatedReader.java)) instead of `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , we will test it, but we have a question that could be important. To solve this problem thinking that was the eol(end of line) character we tried to use the Read() method of the bufferedreader class to read character by character but the problem was the same, the read method hangs forever trying read the first character.  After this comment do you coninue thinking that if we use the class showed by you we will solve the problem??  because in this case the problem is not the end of line because we are trying to read character by character at is the same.

Comment: If the peer software is't writing a single character back, then it's probably thinking that server response is not yet complete. Could you please share the code generating "354 Start mail input" response? It's worth checking if the correct response is generated, incluging proper line terminators.

Comment: we tried to use the new reader that you suggested us, but we got the same problem. hangs forever reading  the data content.  I edit my post adding the source code, do you need more?

Comment: As far as I can see DATA command handling is correct, so the problem is probably not within your code. As a next step I would suggest to contact bank representatives to obtain mail server logs.